# How to get list of records from table where the time difference found using DATEDIFF function between 2 variables that are select queries themselves?

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

```
SET @startdate = (select LOG_TIME from log.time where sender='Japan' and receiver ='USA' and code=158);

SET @enddate = (select LOG_TIME  from log.time where sender='Japan' and receiver ='USA' and code=189);

select * from log.time where  DATEDIFF(minute, @startdate, @enddate) >= 10;
```

Here I want to use 2 variables (@startdate  and @enddate) which are populated with multiple entries coming from the select queries used .

And for the last line , I want the select query to return  a list of records where the DATEDIFF function is greater than or  equal to 10 minutes by using these 2 variables with multiple values .

P.S I am using the Squirrel SQL  Client 2.3 )

The issue is I have no idea if it is possible to use multiple values for variables.

Also please advise or provide any solution to the  above issue such that the query works in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables this way.

Now it's hard to tell for sure not seeing your table schema and sample data but you should be able to do what you want using `JOIN` with a query like this

```
SELECT l1.* 
  FROM log.time l1 JOIN log.time l2
    ON l1.sender = l2.sender
   AND l1.receiver = l2.receiver
   AND l1.code = 158
   AND l2.code = 189
 WHERE l1.sender = 'Japan'
   AND l1.receiver = 'USA'
   AND DATEDIFF(minute, l1.log_time, l2.log_time) >= 10
```

*If you were to provide a table schema, sample data and desired output, then it'll be possible to test your query*